# JavaScript URL checking for pupunder

Tags: javascript, url

I have some javascript that checks the url is "musicmartian.com" and will then run a script that displays a pupunder ad, but doesnt seem to work.

the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href=="musicmartian.com") {
    src='//go.oclaserver.com/apu.php?zoneid=540338'
}
</script>
```

The website is: http://musicmartian.com/ and the ad provider is PropellorAds if thats needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code inside `body` of your html (before `</body>`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.hostname === "musicmartian.com") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//go.oclaserver.com/apu.php?zoneid=540338';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, the code is on http://musicmartian.com/ and still doesn't seem to bring up the ad.